# CSS scrollbar in vuescroll library is not working properly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, scrollbar

I have used the [vuescroll library](https://github.com/YvesCoding/vuescroll) in my Nuxt project and CSS Scrollbar doesn't work when I deactivate Toggle toolbar for different devices.

There is a bug that makes `overflow: scroll` hidden and I am sure that I haven't used this CSS style. When I change `sizeStrategy` to `number` it works but the height exceeds enormously.

Can anyone help me to deactivate this overflow?

```js
ops: {
  vuescroll: {
    mode: 'native',
    sizeStrategy: 'percent',
    locking: true
  },
  bar: {
    showDelay: 500,
    keepShow: true,
    background: '#FFFFFF',
    opacity: 1,
    hoverStyle: false,
    size: '1%',
    disable: false
  },
  scrollPanel: {
    initialScrollY: false,
    initialScrollX: false,
    scrollingX: true,
    scrollingY: false,
    speed: 300,
    easing: undefined,
    verticalNativeBarPos: 'right'
  },
  rail: {
    background: '#A3ACBC',
    opacity: 0.3,
    size: '1%',
    specifyBorderRadius: '1%',
    gutterOfEnds: '0',
    gutterOfSide: '0',
    keepShow: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, we will **probably** need a [repro] here. Pretty hard to debug with just this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi! I solved the problem by uninstalling the library and using css scrollbar instead.Here is the solution for making scroll:**

```
.carousel {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block !important;
  padding-bottom: $spacing-09;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  .featured-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc((#{$column-width-mobile} + #{$column-gap-mobile}) * 11);
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: calc(#{$column-gap-mobile} * 2);
  }
}
#wrapper {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(163, 172, 188, 0.2);
  }
}
```